# Could my character dye her hair with clothing dye or other common materials?

Tags: medieval

- The world is a sort of medieval era place with very widespread trade, so the character would have access to a range of materials from different climates
- The current colour is a blue-ish hue, but that's definitely not permanent- It could be any unnatural hair colour
- It could be clothing dye or any other sort of material accessible to commoners

Comment: Semi-permanent, or wash-in wash-out? If the latter then coffee/red wine works fine. Welcome to the site Lotte, we invite you to take our [tour] and read-up in the [help] on an as-and-when basis when you need guidance as to our ways. Enjoy worldbuilding.

Comment: Thanks! It would probably be semi-permanent.

Comment: Wikipedia lists a few plant-based hair dyes that may work for your scenario:    https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hair_coloring#Plant-based_dyes  Henna in particular has been used as a dye since ancient times.

Comment: You specify unnatural colors that will eliminate most known hair dyes from medieval times, there were quiet a few known.

Comment: Found another, [mushrooms](https://www.bloomanddye.com/journal/2019/2/1/dyeing-with-mushrooms) - yellow, green, orange and brown, who knew? Sorry it's not an answer, I'm busy.

Comment: The conditions and limitations in the proposed duplicate are vastly different from this question. For one, here the OP wants to achieve an unnatural hair colour, while the other question asks for natural hues. The dyes (hence the answers) will be completely different.

Comment: The duplicate's answers include methods for lemon yellow, indigo, beet red, and bleached white hair.

Comment: @rek None of the answers to that question specifies how to produce unnatural colour on human hair. Please note that unnatural hair colours require different dyeing techniques compared to more natural results. For example, if you use blue dye on virgin hair you will not get blue hair unless you are a nordic blond (very light ash blond). Blue and green dyes on natural hair remove yellow and brass (copper-orange) undertones and create a cooler, but still natural, shade.

Comment: @Otkin Neither question asks about specific techniques or preparations, just the material dyes and their utility; what works for one would work for the other. That oversight does not make this question distinct.

Comment: @rek You ignore the stated end goal -- unnatural hair colour. However, I am not going to argue with you. According to my experience talking to you, once you decide to ignore parts of a question it is not possible to convince you otherwise. I hope, though, that, as IT Alex suggested elsewhere, you learn to read between the lines.

Comment: @Otkin Personal attack aside, which part of lemon yellow, indigo, beet red, or bleach white doesn't count as unnatural hair colour? And between which lines of this question am I to read what you've inferred, and why can't the same be said of its duplicate?

Comment: As ever, OP is encouraged to edit the question to make it, and its answers, distinct from its duplicate.

Comment: @rek None of the 5 answers to the proposed duplicate specifies 'lemon yellow, indigo, beet red, or bleach white' as a *result*. The accepted answer talks about ammonia to bleach hair without specifying the end result (no, it will not be platinum blond). The most popular answer suggests several incomplete remedies for black and blond (gold) shades without any specifics. One answer does not propose any specific dyes at all. One answer suggests using soot or ash to dirty hair and hide the original colour. And one answer proposes indigo or woad as a blue tint to achieve shades of brown or black.

Comment: In addition to this, procedures matter for the end results. Without the correct procedures, it is impossible to obtain the results specified in the OP. Moreover, bleach white (aka platinum blonde) is completely impossible using medieval techniques unless the base hair colour is already light blonde: The bleaches of that time were extremely damaging and the hair will break at a touch if overprocessed. Look at the paintings, there are no beauties with pure white hair. Most of them have orangey-yellow hair.

Comment: You cannot ignore the end result and the process that leads to it. If you do, you risk finding yourself in a situation where, for example, rape and consensual sex are completely indistinguishable. Because if we follow your line of reasoning, both of them are nothing more than sexual intercourse: What works for one would work for another.

Comment: @Otkin Poking holes in the other question or its answers does not change that this one is a duplicate of it. If the original question can be improved, you should definitely go suggest or make the edits necessary, and/or supply a better answer than what is currently given.

Comment: @Otkin This question is all of three bullets and each one is a duplicated detail of the other: 1. Medieval period. 2. Dye hair. 3. Accessible materials. Where they differ is natural/unnatural hair colours, but the other question has answers that cover that too. You have failed to make the case that this one is somehow distinct, regardless of how much you read into it or fault the original. Please figure out how this site works before you hound me again.

Comment: @rek I should've asked this before. Do you understand how hair dyes work? Do you know how unnatural hair colours are achieved?

Comment: Hello @Lotte, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. Your first question has been a bit cantankerous, and I apologize for that. It sometimes happens. As you'll learn should you continue with the Stack (and I very much hope you do!), asking a clear and concise question is harder than it looks. Otkin asked a [meta question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8392/40609) about the closure of your question. As I indicate in my answer, I think this should be reopened - but the Q needs to be improved a bit first. Please visit the link. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Pick your color, if it can dye wool it will dye hair just fine.

Here is a great photo showing a list of known natural dyes, all are possible with medieval technology. several were not available in the real medieval era because they come from the Americas. You can also have things link woad, henna, and saffron for blue, reds, and orange respectively. Keep in mind as hair grow they will have to re-dye periodically no matter what, you can't dye something that does not exist yet. And of course bleaching your hair was a well known technique at the time.

Purity and boldness of color will be affected by cost of course, these would represent the more expensive dyes. keep in mind a commoner probably cannot afford expensive dye so they would be mostly limited to earth tones, nothing unnatural. These would be Henna (red/brown), Madder(red), onionskins (yellow), alderbark (orange), walnut (brown/black)

**For an unnatural color at low cost your best bet is green** which can be achieved with a variety of homemade dyes, although far fewer than you think. known ways to achieve that are.

Heather and alum

green lichen

Iris leaves

Pivet berries and salt (this can also produce a purplish red so may not be the best choice.)

[image]

These are also the ones that are not downright toxic, using lead (black) or lye bleaching were common at the time but were also toxic.

Note also depending on your initial hair color you may have to bleach it before dying, dye can't do much to black hair for instance.

Comment: Just to add, indigo is a common and still available plant dye that also works well on hair. It will make dark hair darker and lighter hair blueish purple.

Comment: Woad grows as a weed in Europe (and is considered a noxious/invasive weed in the Americas). It's not quite as blue as indigo (doesn't have as high of a concentration--technically it is still indigo), but it's still definitely blue, and if you bleach first it will definitely be an unnatural hair color. You need to get the chemistry right to prepare it, but it was very common in the medieval era. (Source: I watched a YouTube video where someone went out and harvested her own woad from random roadside plants and used it to dye stuff blue.)

Comment: I second woad. Woad-based dyes produce a range of colours from blue to turquoise. However, the dying process can be somewhat complicated and require several sessions to achieve deeper hues. The hair will have to be bleached prior to the application of the woad dye. One thing I am not sure about is the condition of the hair after all this processing. PH of woad dye is not 7. According to the fabric hand-dyeing manuals, some formulations are harmful to protein-based fibres. I am not a chemist, so someone needs to verify this part and see how woad dye would interact with human hair.

Comment: @Ivana yes indigo is another good choice, there are literally dozens of other plant based dyes, I couldn't list them all.

Answer (score 5):

In medieval times dyes could be very expensive for certain tones, while being pretty common and cheap for other.

My grandmother (well past medieval times) used to dye her hair using walnuts and remembered that, while doing laundry with the old method (stacking layers of clothes and ashes, then pouring hot water multiple times), one should be careful to not use the ashes of a certain tree which would have dyed all the laundry with an unwanted color (I am not 100%, but I seem to remember it was rhododendron).

So, some dyes are surely pretty common, but don't expect any flashy or bright color: the reason why purple and red are colors associated with nobility is that in the past they were pretty expensive, so only well off people could afford paying for getting it. Unless your character is rich, they will have to settle for more dull/common ones.

Comment: Interesting!  What are tree "hashes"?

Comment: @AlexanderNied a poor typo for ashes

Comment: Ah, got it! That makes sense-- I had read that lye for soap could be made with hardwood ash, so it is probably the same or a similar process for cleaning of clothes.  Thanks!

Comment: I'd challenge the complete inability to get a dye without being rich. Someone has to be the creator and seller of the dye - if MC can create their own, there is no need to purchase (although if they can create their own, they could become rich anyway, by making additional and selling it)

Comment: If you apply henna on bleached hair you will get very bright hues ranging from yellow (similar to banana) to orange. Other dyes will also produce much brighter colours than you are expecting if the hair is prepared by bleaching. Blue and green are not out of the realm of possibilities. Red, orange, yellow are very much possible and rather easy to achieve.

Comment: @TCooper Technically yes, the maker of the purple dye could use it. However, the process took thousands of shellfish and a lot of labor to make. Thus, only the very rich could afford to have anyone do that much labor. The people making the dye could sell it for so much that it made sense to sell it and use the money to buy food instead of trying to use it themselves.

Comment: @DavidR I was thinking more of woad/indigo dye followed by kermes dye - still a lot of manual production but (I think, no expert) more feasible for a single person to handle/create/perfect a the process. Would still probably need suppliers though - or a special (read fictional) method for catching the bugs in enough quantity. I thought that method was more common in medieval Europe anyway, with the shells being a Roman Empire method they lost in the dark ages? (Again, no expert, open to correction)